# Key Size in RSA C# is not changing !

Tags: c#, rsa, encryption-asymmetric, private-key

I am generating key pair and store them in xml file using

```
ToXmlString(true);
```

I need to set the key size to 2048
according to the MSDN the only place to do this is from the constructor of the RSACryptoServiceProvider

```
    private void AssignParameter(ProviderType providerType)
    {
        CspParameters cspParams;

        cspParams = new CspParameters((int)providerType);
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = RSAEncryption.containerName;
        cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        cspParams.ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider";
        cspParams.KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Exchange;

        this.rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);
    }
```

when I check the key size using

```
int x = this.rsa.KeySize;
```

I always get 1024
so whats the wrong here??

Comment: Your code worked for me and I got 2048 back.  What are you passing for providerType?  I used a value of 1 (PROV_RSA_FULL) when creating cspParams.  I also passed my own string into cspParams.KeyContainerName.

Comment: I am using the PROV_RSA_FULL also with the value of 1 and also my one string to the KeyContainerName property !

Comment: I am getting " Message Object already exists."

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this before, try changing the container name or try

```
using (this.rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams)) 
{

}
```

or `this.rsa.Clear();` after you are done with it.

If you already have a container with the same name it will re-use the container I believe.

Comment: yes noticed same problem, deleted the container and imported a larger key, still fails. Created a new container with different name and it worked fine !

Answer (score 1):

You need first to clear the existing container like this:

```
rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
rsa.Clear();
```

Then it should work with you.
Don't forget to set:

```
rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
```